# Не добавляет элементы в массив

Tags: javascript

Собственно, вот чем я сбит с толку.

Имею массив и функцию в которой пытаюсь добавить новый элемент:

```js
var ar = {};

function Foo() {

  ar['ass'] = { 0: 'big', 1: 'very_big' };

}

Foo();
console.log(ar);
```

когда вызываю функцию консоль выдает ошибку

```
Cannot set property 'ass' of null
```

НО! если делать добавление вне функции, то все прекрасно добавляется.

Тоже самое и с обычным массивом, т.е. в функции ничего не работает.

---

Как оказалось все работает, просто в коде я раньше вызывал другую функцию которая, делала не то и в итоге ar = null

Comment: телепатия плюс асинхронность

Comment: в сниппете все работает, отредактируй его так, чтобы проблема воспроизвелась